# WebApi Deployed to IIS: Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have two Api's that are deployed and running fine in my local IIS. They deploy fine and swagger works but executing any method returns a **TypeError: Failed to fetch** Error. Then I run the same GET in Postman and it throws **Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop**

Has anyone seen this before? We are going through an Azure App Gateway...could that be a problem?

-Ken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Gateway turned out to be the problem. I commented out the app.UseHttpsRedirection() and the problems went away.

Answer (score 3):

Remove  app.UseHttpsRedirection() from Program.cs